# Check if elements of 2D array have equal values at equal indices

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if elements of a given 2D array has equal values at indices that have same subscript or index.

For example, given an array;

`var arr = [[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]`

Here `arr[0][0]`, `arr[1][0]` and `arr[2][0]` are equal for the same index `0`.

Similarly, I want to check every other set of elements which have same "row" or same "column" (or both). How do I achieve that?

I have tried looping through the array, checking three consecutive elements but it returns `TypeError` as succeeding or preceding elements don't exist for all the element under the loop.

This is what I am doing, assuming a `3x3` array;

```js
 var arr = [[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if ((arr[i][j] == arr[i - 1][j] == arr[i - 2][j]) == 1) {
          //do something
        }
      }
    }
```

Output:

```
   "message": "TypeError: arr[(i - 1)] is undefined",
   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
   "lineno": 16,
   "colno": 9
```

Comment: please add the result of the above check.

Comment: In the first iteration of both loops, you are checking against `arr[i - 2][j]` with `i=0`, meaning you are trying to access `arr[-2][j]` which shouldn't work for normal arrays

Comment: You said  *Here* `arr[0][0]`, `arr[0][1]` and `arr[0][2]` *are equal for the same index 0* but each of those element have different values. Not sure what you are asking. `arr[0][0]` and `arr[0][2]` are equal but not all three.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I know that's the issue. Just can't get it to work.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Sorry for the mistake. I meant `arr[0][0]`,`arr[1][0]` and `arr[2][0]` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You could take two nested loop and check if same rows or cols contains the same values.

```js
var array = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]],
    cols = array.map((a, i, outer) => a.every((v, j) => outer[0][j] === v)),
    rows = array.map((a, i) => a.every((v, j, inner) => inner[0] === v));


array.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
console.log('cols', ...cols);
console.log('rows', ...rows);
```